# Unity C# - Hide / Unhide a Button in a different scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm exploring a bit in Unity and C#, I searched everywhere for a solution without luck.

**Problem:**

- In Scene A, I have an object button called "Button_2" -> it's hidden.
- In Scene B, I have another button called "Button_1", and this one, must unhide "Button_2", in the other scene "Scene A"

How can I achieve this, if possible of course?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**
I tried the following:

- Used DontDestroyOnLoad. Basically can't use it on a single button. Unity doesnt allow it. So, I had to do it on the canvas, but when I switched to another scene, was a huge mess with both scenes mixed.
- Tried Yuris solution and suggestions and didn't work. Scenes just don't interact with each other at all.
- Tried to combine both of above with the prefab concept Yuris suggested aswell and still no luck.

I will keep doing my best, but my knowledge is very limited. I'll be back with more feedback if I make progress.

**EDIT 2:**

- Made many experiments with a non monobehaviour script file and class with only variables to be accessed by a script file that is linked to gameobjects in the diferent scenes.
  I wasnt hable to access the variables on the non monobehaviour file. Looks like unity doesn't like non monobehaviour and didn't work.

Comment: Store the data in a place that persists across scene changes and have `Button_L2` check that place for its state information.

Comment: I already used DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); and assigned to the Button_L2, but I can't unhide it from another scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the button a prefab and assign it on a script in the Scene B, and then when you load scene A again, it will be active.

Remember that if you use that prefab anywhere else, it will be active there too.

Example:

[image: Project]
[image: Inspector]
[image: Hierarchy]

Example.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        button.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: My scenes are separate. If I put them like that everything will overlap. They are called when required.

Comment: Ye, that's how I tested, I put them together just for the screenshot. It should work. You'll have to Load/Unload Scene A, and you're fine. Because the script changed the prefab itself. So if the prefab was Inactive by default, after the Scene B was loaded, the prefab should be active.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't work, I need the button to do the work.  Do you know a way to "search" the button from scene A from scene B?

Comment: You can rename the function ("void Awake()" to "public void ShowButton()") and use it on a button, and it'll work. I'll prepare something up in the morning if you didn't get this to work.

Comment: Ok. I can't test it right now but I will give it another try as soon as I can. Thank you for your assistence!

Comment: I just wraped my head arround this, and i'm really sorry, but my experience doesn't allow me to understand how I can achieve this. Can you assist me a bit more please, if you can?

Comment: Hello again, looks like I was doing something wrong. It worked! Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't replied, I didn't saw. No problem. Glad that you did it. <3